# Return the index of a row based on value in different dataframe's row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes. They all contain 3 decimal point float values.

Dataframe A is a one column dataframe with 12 rows. Dataframe B is a one column dataframe with over 40,000 rows, which contain the 12 values in Dataframe A spread out randomly.

I need to find the indices of the values in Dataframe A within Dataframe B.

I have tried `.query()`, `.index.value()` and `.where()` but am unable to return the indices.

#### Dataframe A

| Row Index | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 148.521 |
| 1 | 112.379 |
| ... | ... |
| 12 | 510.121 |

### Dataframe B

| Row Index | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.000 |
| 1 | 0.025 |
| ... | ... |
| 46871 | 1171.675 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.loc[]

```
for i in dataframe_A['Time']:
  dataframe_B.loc[dataframe_B['Time'] == i]
```

This should return the twelve values along with their row index from dataframe B

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's almost working, I get the following output below by wrapping the second line of your answer in a `print()`.

`[46871 rows x 1 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Time [s]]
Index: []`

I get 12 of these lines.

Comment: Only way I was able to reproduce that output was by searching for values from df_A  that are not in df_B. So my best guess would be that none of those 12 values are actually present inside the larger dataframe.

Comment: Try adding a value to dataframe A that you are 100% sure is inside dataframe B and see what output you get. If it returns the index then you can be certain the other 12 are not present, if you get empty again then it's a syntax or logic error in your code.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and due to rounding I am doing in my code they will be unable to be found in the other dataframe. Thank you for your help!